Can NSwag generate a DayJS duration from a C# TimeSpan?
Im changing from moment to dayjs in my projects and running into a little issue. A C# TimeSpan was generated as a moment.Duration before now as a dayjs.Dayjs (by setting "dateTimeType": "DayJS" in the .nswag).
But is it possible to generate it as a duration?
